# Workaround for <thead> and <tfoot> being printed on every page in webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit, rotativa

WebKit prints `<thead>` and `<tfoot>` only on the first page. According to [W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3) `<thead>` and `<tfoot>`:

> When long tables are printed, the table head and foot information may be repeated on each page that contains table data

We are using Rotativa which is based on WebKit for rendering PDF and having issues with `thead` and `tfoot` not being rended on every page.

Is there any workaround or toggle to solve this?

Comment: "When long tables are printed, the table head and foot information **may** be repeated on each page that contains table data." - There is no requirement for a user agent to repeat them, so it's wrong to call it a bug.  Original definitions of "may", "must" etc [are here](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt)

Comment: Does [this CSS](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/10/12/repeating-html-table-headers-on-each-printed-page/) help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. It's not working in Webkit

Comment: I don't think there is a solution for this. You could check if there is a feature request or issue at _Rotativa_  and if not open an issue there. Maybe with a link to [Bug 17205 - THEAD & TFOOT should be printed on every page](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17205) or [Issue 24826: Repeating table headers on printed pages](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24826) and maybe also [Table header (thead) wont appear on every page when print on Chrome #13544](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/13544)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BEGIN HACK`

Finally, I used following JS script to split my table into multiple pages:

```
<script>
    function splitTable(table, maxHeight, firstPageMaxHeight) {
        var header = table.children("thead");
        if (!header.length)
            return;

        var headerHeight = header.outerHeight();
        var header = header.detach();

        var splitIndices = [0];
        var rows = table.children("tbody").children();

        maxHeight -= headerHeight;
        var currHeight = 0;
        var firstPage = true;
        rows.each(function (i, row) {
            currHeight += $(rows[i]).outerHeight();
            if (firstPage) {
                currHeight += (maxHeight - firstPageMaxHeight);
                firstPage = false;
            }
            if (currHeight > maxHeight) {
                splitIndices.push(i);
                currHeight = $(rows[i]).outerHeight();

            }
        });
        splitIndices.push(undefined);

        table = table.replaceWith('<div id="_split_table_wrapper"></div>');
        table.empty();

        for (var i = 0; i < splitIndices.length - 1; i++) {
            var newTable = table.clone();
            header.clone().appendTo(newTable);
            $('<tbody />').appendTo(newTable);
            rows.slice(splitIndices[i], splitIndices[i + 1]).appendTo(newTable.children('tbody'));
            newTable.appendTo("#_split_table_wrapper");
            if (splitIndices[i + 1] !== undefined) {
                $('<div style="page-break-after: always; margin:0; padding:0; border: none;"></div>').appendTo("#_split_table_wrapper");
            }
        }
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        splitTable($(".po-report"), 2100, 600);
    });
</script>
```

`END HACK`